# Django Rest Framework using the url to load specified models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to use generic url settings to implement the django rest interface for all models in django?

So instead of per model configuration:

```
class BlogResource(ModelResource):
    model = Blog

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^Blog/$', ListOrCreateModelView.as_view(resource=BlogResource)),
    url(r'^Blog/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$', InstanceModelView.as_view(resource=BlogResource)),
)
```

A more generic type of loading:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<model>\w+)/$', GenericView.render_model_list()),
    url(r'^(?P<model>\w+)/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$', GenericView.render_model()),
)
```

With something that allows the system to generate the model and render it to the rest interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class BlogResource(ModelResource):
    model = Blog

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^Blog/$', ListOrCreateModelView.as_view(resource=BlogResource)),
    url(r'^Blog/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$', InstanceModelView.as_view(resource=BlogResource)),
)
```

in more general way the solution would look like this (sorry - i wrote it by hand), but you still need to import these models and form the model tuple by hand.

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url
from models import Model1, Model2, Model3

urlconf = ['', ]

for obj in (Model1, Model2, Model3):
    name = obj.__class__.__name__
    ResourceClass = type('%sResource' % name, (obj,), {
        'model': obj,
    })
    urlconf.append(url(r'^%s/$' % name, ListOrCreateModelView.as_view(resource=ResourceClass)))
    urlconf.append(url(r'^%s/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$' % name, ListOrCreateModelView.as_view(resource=ResourceClass)))
urlpatterns = patterns(urlconf)
```